# Enable AccessoryDetailButton even if cell is disabled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to have my UITableViewCell disabled but still be able to press the accessoryView button.

I thought this would work:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
cell.accessoryView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

But my UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton is still disabled.

Answer (score 0):

accessoryView will get all his touchEvents from his superview, in this case your cell and wont react to your actions.

What might work is creating a touch event to that accesoryView on the viewController you make the tableView on and make it react to touches.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{  
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == accessoryView) {
        //do something because you hit accessoryView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you disable a view, all its subviews will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to set userInteractionEnabled =NO all subviews in cell expect in Disclosure and cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Place this line in this method.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   Leave this method blank. if u want to code in this delegate method so filter those row by code:  
 if(indexPath.row == row no in which u don't want click event)  
 {
    leave blank
 }
 else
 {
   code which u want .
 }
}
```

you get your click event for particular button in this method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```